# Space isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and denote by $\textbf{R}^X$ the set of all functions $f: X \to \textbf{R}$. I know that $\textbf{R}^X$ is a vector space under the operations$$(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x),\text{ and }(r \cdot f)(x) = r \cdot f(x)$$ My question is, how can I see that for $X$ being the finite set $\{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ the space above is isomorphic to $\textbf{R}^n$?

Comment: A finite sequence is exactly the same as a function from $n$ to $\mathbf{R}$. You just put the values $(f(1), …, f(n))$

Answer (score 2):

Let

$$\Phi: \Bbb R^X\to \Bbb R^n,\; f\mapsto (f(1),\ldots,f(n))$$
then we have easily 
$$\Phi(\alpha f+g)=\alpha\Phi(f)+\Phi(g)$$
and that $\Phi$ is bijective. Conclude.

Comment: @John For $x = (x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, take $f$ to be such that $f(i) = x_i$.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the other correct answer(s), you can show that $R^X$ is $n$-dimensional by finding $n$ basis vectors. Let $f_i$ be a function such that $f_i(i) = 1$ and $f_i(j) = 0$ for all other $j$. Showing that $f_1,\ldots,f_n$ are linearly independent and spanning is easy in this case.