# $\textbf{R}^\textbf{N}$ is space of all sequences $\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\}$ with pointwise operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

Followup to my last question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437561/space-isomorphic-to-mathbbrn/1437565).

Let $X$ be a nonempty set, and denote by $\textbf{R}^X$ the set of all functions $f: X \to \textbf{R}$. How do I see that for $X = \textbf{N}$ the set of natural numbers, the space $\textbf{R}^\textbf{N}$ is the space of all sequences $\{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty\}$ with pointwise operations?

Answer (score 2):

A sequence is the same thing as a function on $\mathbb N$ - just change your notation from $x_n$ to $x(n)$ and $x$ becomes a function $\mathbb N \to \mathbb R$, since the valid values for $n$ are exactly the natural numbers.